# Открытие локальных файлов в браузере на Webkit+Gtk

Tags: python, python-3.x, gtk, webkit

Задача написать простой браузер с возможностью открытия любых локальных файлов. Мне не удалось найти способа реализации открытия диалогового окна для выбора файла, который будет открыт в браузере.

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
gi.require_version('WebKit2', '4.0')

from gi.repository import Gtk, WebKit2

window = Gtk.Window()
window.set_default_size(800, 600)
window.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)

scrolled_window = Gtk.ScrolledWindow()
webview = WebKit2.WebView()
webview.load_uri("https://google.com")
scrolled_window.add(webview)

window.add(scrolled_window)
window.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
fc = Gtk.FileChooserDialog(
    title = "Open File",
    parent = window,
    action = Gtk.FileChooserAction.OPEN
)

fc.add_buttons(
    Gtk.STOCK_OPEN,
    Gtk.ResponseType.ACCEPT
)

res = fc.run()
if res == Gtk.ResponseType.ACCEPT:
    webview.load_uri(fc.get_uri())
fc.destroy()
```